# Trying to get images from a site using tags

Tags: python, discord.py

So. i made a new project in pycharm and i set this bit of code up. it gives no syntax errors and im almost certain its all correct (although i am new i actually though this would work)

Problem: When i run the py file it instantly closes. even in command prompt i don't know why.. the only file i have is aiz.py

Any help is appreciated thanks.

I have tried changing areas of the code.

```
import discord
import json
import random, requests

from discord.ext import commands



TOKEN = 'TOKENHERE'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    client.run(TOKEN)


class NSFW(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@client.event
async def rule34(self, ctx, *, tags: str):
    await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
    try:
        data = requests.get(
            "http://rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit={}&tags={}".format(tags),
            headers={"User-Agent": "linux:memebot:v1.0.0"})
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        await ctx.send(("nsfw.no_results_found", ctx).format(tags))
        return

    count = len(data)
    if count == 0:
        await ctx.send(("nsfw.no_results_found", ctx).format(tags))
        return
    image_count = 4
    if count < 4:
        image_count = count
    images = []
    for i in range(image_count):
        image = data[random.randint(0, count)]
        images.append("http://img.rule34.xxx/images/{}/{}".format(image["directory"], image["image"]))
    await ctx.send(("nsfw.results", ctx).format(image_count, count, tags, "\n".join(images)))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('>test'):
            msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(NSFW(bot))
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling any of your functions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/2011147) if you are new to Python.

Comment: Remove your token! Its not smart to just show it to the public.

Comment: thank you for telling me @Axois i am resetting it rn

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off in several places, and you seem to be confused about the difference between a command and an event.  Events are only applicable to the names listed in the [Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) or the [Command Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#event-reference).  You usually want to use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) instead.

`run` should be the last line in your script.  When you call `run`, nothing after that will be called until the bot has finished running.

[Cogs are classes for organizing and sharing bot code](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html).  Generally you would have your Cog in a separate file that you would reference from your main file.  I'll write the below code such that you have the main bot code in `mainbot.py` and the cog code in `nsfw.py`

mainbot.py

---

```
from discord.ext import commands    

TOKEN = 'TOKENHERE'

bot = commands.Bot('!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

bot.load_extension('nsfw')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

nsfw.py

---

```
import discord
import json
import random, requests
from discord.ext import commands

class NSFW(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def rule34(self, ctx, *, tags: str):
        await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
        try:
            data = requests.get(
                "http://rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit={}&tags={}".format(tags),
                headers={"User-Agent": "linux:memebot:v1.0.0"})
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            await ctx.send(("nsfw.no_results_found", ctx).format(tags))
            return

        count = len(data)
        if count == 0:
            await ctx.send(("nsfw.no_results_found", ctx).format(tags))
            return
        image_count = 4
        if count < 4:
            image_count = count
        images = []
        for i in range(image_count):
            image = data[random.randint(0, count)]
            images.append("http://img.rule34.xxx/images/{}/{}".format(image["directory"], image["image"]))
        await ctx.send(("nsfw.results", ctx).format(image_count, count, tags, "\n".join(images)))

    @commands.command()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await ctx.send(msg)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(NSFW(bot))
```